ROS2 Ackermann Steering Car is not moving and wheels are not turning
I've been trying to figure out why my robot will not turn or move forward in Gazebo or Rviz2. I'm using ROS2 Humble and the ros2_control for the Ackermann Controller. So far, my robot properly spawns in but I can't control it with teleop_twist_keyboard. From what I understand teleop_twist_keyboard listens to /cmd_vel and I have tried remapping /asc/controller_state to /cmd_vel, but that still didn't allow me to control the robot.
EDIT - The problem was fixed by using stamped_twist

Please post solution as an actual answer and not as an edit to the question. Please take the [tour] to better understand how the Q&A mechanism of Stack Exchange works. Thanks
